# Springboot jasypt encryption in weblogic

Tags: spring, security, encryption, boot, jasypt

I have developed a springboot web project (.war) for deploying in weblogic. I am using jasypt for encrypting sensitive properties that are in application.properties file.

I can run the application by following way

> mvn spring-boot:run
> -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--jasypt.encryptor.password=masterpassword

or

> java -Djasypt.encryptor.password=masterpassword -jar
> springboot-jasypt-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

but the problem arises when I am deploying this in weblogic server. I am packaging the application skipping the test which allows me to get the war file and I am not sure where I can keep the secret key in weblogic. Also where should that key be stored in a secured way .

**p.s  Vault secret management is not in place**

Answer (score 1):

How about you put it into an environment variable and pass the value of the environment variable in the script? This way you can have the secret on the server already waiting for you. This is [12 factor compliant](https://12factor.net/config) by the way.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the 12 factor app, it is useful,